# Python String to Int Or None

Tags: python

Learning Python and a little bit stuck.

I'm trying to set a variable to equal `int(stringToInt)` or if the string is empty set to `None`.

I tried to do `variable = int(stringToInt) or None` but if the string is empty it will error instead of just setting it to None.

Do you know any way around this?

Comment: Define 'empty'? Is `' '` empty? Any white space?

Comment: This is almost the reverse question to [Python: most idiomatic way to convert None to empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034573/python-most-idiomatic-way-to-convert-none-to-empty-string)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want a one-liner like you've attempted, go with this:

```
variable = int(stringToInt) if stringToInt else None
```

This will assign `variable` to `int(stringToInt)` only if is not empty AND is "numeric". If, for example `stringToInt` is `'mystring'`, a `ValueError` will be raised.

To avoid `ValueError`s, so long as you're not making a generator expression, use a try-except:

```
try:
    variable = int(stringToInt)
except ValueError:
    variable = None
```

Comment: This bears explanation in detail for a novice.

Comment: The one-liner returns None when stringToInt = 0. Better would be: `variable = int(stringToInt) if stringToInt is not None else None`.

Comment: @kadee if `stringToInt` is `0` then it is not a string. You're right though, that the one-liner will only work for strings, which was what the question was asking about. Also, your proposed solution wouldn't work for empty strings and would raise the same exception OP was receiving. =)

Answer (score 30):

I think this is the clearest way:

```
variable = int(stringToInt) if stringToInt.isdigit() else None
```

Comment: This won't work where stringToInt is None as that doesn't have an isdigit()

Comment: You can strengthen it with check for None like  `variable = int(stringToInt) if stringToInt and stringToInt.isdigit() else None`

Comment: isdigit is unsafe because it recognizes unicode power-of-2, ² , as a digit. isdecimal is the safe way. So: `variable = int(stringToInt) if stringToInt and stringToInt.isdecimal() else None`

Answer (score 21):

Use the fact that it generates an exception:

```
try:
  variable = int(stringToInt)
except ValueError:
  variable = None
```

This has the pleasant side-effect of binding `variable` to `None` for other common errors: `stringToInt='ZZTop'`, for example.

Comment: I think this solution is probably the best as it will handle situations where the string contains non-digit characters as well.

Comment: Doesn't handle `None`, as calling `int()` on it raises another exception: _"TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"_

Answer (score 5):

this will parse stringToInt to int if it's valid and return original value if it's '' or None

```
variable = stringToInt and int(stringToInt)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some options:

Catch the exception and handle it:

```
try:
    variable = int(stringToInt)
except ValueError, e:
    variable = None
```

It's not really that exceptional, account for it:

```
   variable = None
   if not stringToInt.isdigit():
       variable = int(stringtoInt)
```

Comment: You don't need the `all()`. `if stringToInt.isdigit():` is sufficient.

Comment: Wow, not my day.  Certainly not my best answer.  I corrected it, but I'm resisting the urge to delete my answer as my penance.