# How to remove unicode characters from Dictionary data in python

Tags: python, json, unicode

After using request library , am getting below dict in response.json()

```
{u'xyz': {u'key1': None, u'key2': u'Value2'}}
```

I want to remove all unicode characters and print only key value pairs without unicode chars

I have tried below method to remove , but it shows malformed string

```
>>> import json, ast
>>> c = {u'xyz': {u'key1': None,u'key2': u'Value2'}}
>>> ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(c))
```

Getting 'ValueError: malformed string'

Any suggestion on how to do it ?

Comment: Is this Python3 or 2 ?

Comment: What is the output you want, and why?

Comment: try using `json.dumps(c)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your None to 'None':

```
 c = {u'xyz': {u'key1': 'None', u'key2': u'Value2'}}
```

it is a casting issue - ast likes str's

Also, maybe u want to change all None to empty str or 'None' str...
See this thread :
[Python: most idiomatic way to convert None to empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034573/python-most-idiomatic-way-to-convert-none-to-empty-string)
with this code, i've changes  the empty string to 'None':

```
def xstr(s):
    if s is None:
        return 'None'
    return str(s)
```

Comment: Then it becomes a string with "None" as the value, completely different from  None.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet will helps you to preserve the data without unicode prefix notation `u` :

```
>>> import json
>>> c = {u'xyz': {u'key1': u'Value1',u'key2': u'Value2'}}
>>> print c
{u'xyz': {u'key2': u'Value2', u'key1': u'Value1'}}
>>> d = eval(json.dumps(c))
>>> print d
{'xyz': {'key2': 'Value2', 'key1': 'Value1'}}
```

[json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) will convert the dict to string type and [eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) will reverse it.

*Note: key1 value has changed from None to 'value1' for testing purpose*

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you want this. Your variable is a normal Python dict with normal Unicode strings, and they happen to be printed as `u''` to distinguish them from bytestrings, but that shouldn't matter for using them.

If you want to save them as strings to read them as data later, JSON is a fine format for that. So no need to call request's `.json()` function at all, just use the response's `.text` attribute -- it's already JSON, after all.

Your try

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(c))
```

Fails because you first turn `c` into JSON again, and then try to parse it as a Python literal. That doesn't work because Python isn't JSON; in particular one has `null` and the other has `None`.

So maybe you want to change the Unicode strings into bytestrings? Like by encoding them as UTF8, that might work:

```
def to_utf8(d):
    if type(d) is dict:
        result = {}
        for key, value in d.items():
            result[to_utf8(key)] = to_utf8(value)
        return result
    elif type(d) is unicode:
        return d.encode('utf8')
    else:
        return d
```

Or something like that, but I don't know why you would need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unicodestring.encode("ascii","replace")`

```
>>> ustr=u'apple'
>>> ustr
u'apple'
>>> astr=ustr.encode("ascii","replace")
>>> astr
'apple'
```

Comment: This for strings not for dict