# Print empty string if variable is None

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a templated string that will print values of a given dict. However, the key may or may not exist in the dict. If it doesn't exist, I'd like it to return an empty string instead.

To demonstrate what I mean, let's say I have a dict:

```
test_dict = { 1: "a", 2: "b"}
```

And a template string:

```
'{} {} {}'.format(test_dict.get(1), test_dict.get(2), test_dict.get(3))
```

I'd like the following output:

```
'a b '
```

But instead I get:

```
'a b None'
```

Comment: Your template string explicitly contains a comma and a space following the second item, so your desired output is impossible.

Comment: Fixed the mistake

Comment: It still contains a space following the second item, so the desired output is still impossible.

Comment: Ok fixed again. That's not the point of my question though. The last placeholder to print an empty string instead of `None`.

Comment: You can pass an extra argument to `.get()` to specify a return value if the key is not found, instead of the default `None`.  Use `test_dict.get(3, '')` and it will return a blank string.

Comment: Ahh yes this is what I'm looking for, thank you.

Comment: Now that you mention the extra space though, is there a way to remove the placeholder completely if key doesn't exist?

Comment: Not if you use a fixed string template.  You'd have to build it dynamically, and only add the space and the third value if it exists.

Comment: Or this, but it's kind of ugly `'{} {}{}'.format(test_dict.get(1), test_dict.get(2), (' ' + test_dict.get(3)) if test_dict.get(3) else '')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the dictionary's `get` function.  This allows you to specify a value to return if the key is not found

```
'{}, {}, {}'.format(test_dict.get(1,''), test_dict.get(2,''), test_dict.get(3, ''))
```

Comment: This would also make a good answer on [Python: most idiomatic way to convert None to empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034573/python-most-idiomatic-way-to-convert-none-to-empty-string), then we could close this question into that as a (near-)duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATES PER OP COMMENT**

You can use the `string` library to help here. See the below script using your `test_dict`:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/51359690
from string import Formatter

class NoneAsEmptyFormatter(Formatter):
    def get_value(self, key, args, kwargs):
        v = super().get_value(key, args, kwargs)
        return ' ' if v is None else v

fmt = NoneAsEmptyFormatter()

test_dict = { 1: "a", 2: "b"}

test_str = fmt.format('{} {} {}', test_dict.get(1), test_dict.get(2), test_dict.get(3))

print(test_str)
```

We build a quick `NoneAsEmptyFormatter` class and use that to format the strings in coming from the dict.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of why it's causing None. I'm wondering how I can change my template string though, so it returns an empty string instead of `None` in the event that the key does not exist.

Comment: Editing post now per OP's comments after my original post answered the first version of the question (for whoever carelessly downvoted)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get the length of the dict, and put the same amount of placeholeders inside the template:

```
In [27]: test_dict = { 1: "a", 2: "b"}                                                                                                                                                                      

In [28]: ' '.join(['{}'] * len(test_dict))                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[28]: '{} {}'

In [29]: ' '.join(['{}'] * len(test_dict)).format(*test_dict.values())                                                                                                                                      
Out[29]: 'a b'
```

---

Note that, this is basically the same as `' '.join(test_dict.values())` but showing you the template string as an example.

Comment: Why not just do `' '.join(test_dict.values())`?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, that's the plan. Showing the template string for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Re [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227323/print-empty-string-is-variable-is-none#comment100959039_57227323),

> Now that you mention the extra space though, is there a way to remove the placeholder completely if key doesn't exist?

Yes, this is possible. Just make a list of values, filter out any `None`s, then join the result:

```
In [3]: values = map(test_dict.get, [1, 2, 3])

In [4]: ' '.join(v for v in values if v is not None)
Out[4]: 'a b'
```

Or if order is not important, or if you're using Python 3.7+ and you want to preserve insertion order, you can skip some steps:

```
In [5]: ' '.join(test_dict.values())
Out[5]: 'a b'
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but unfortunately in my case, the order is important.

Comment: @doctopus Oh, option 1 preserves order.  Option 2 might not.