# python alternative regex search return tuple with None

Tags: python, regex, tuples

I have the following script tha that gets the service_name of a tnsfiles if available if not it get the SID 
it seems to work fine but it is returning me tuples that I am unable to parse

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

regexes = re.compile(r'SERVICE_NAME\s?=\s?(.+?)\)|SID\s?=\s?(.+?)\)')

with open('tnsnames.ora.test') as tns_file:
    for tnsname in tns_file:
        match = regexes.search(tnsname)

        if match:
          print(match.groups())
```

the script returns the following:

```
(None, 'db1')
('db2', None)
('db3', None)
```

but I only want to have the name of the db returned not the None

how can I strip the "None" from the output. 
i cannot use re.findall because there are some lines in the tnsnames that have a service_name and a sid and then I will have duplicates.

how can I parse the output of match regex object to ignore the none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.groups()` method that returns all captured values even if they are empty. Since the regex contains an alternation with a capturing group in each, one of them will always be empty upon a valid match.

A **generic solution** for this is to filter out a *None* value from the two item tuple, and you may do that using [a lot of approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034573/python-most-idiomatic-way-to-convert-none-to-empty-string). One way is to concat the two values:

```
m = match.groups()
print(r'{}{}'.format(m[0] or '', m[1] or ''))
```

The `m[x] or ''` syntax is OK here as we can only have a string or `None` in the `match.groups()`.

Another solution is to **re-write the pattern so that it contains just 1 capturing group**.

It is easy to make the pattern contain a single group as the part matching between parentheses is duplicated in both alternatives:

```
r'(?:SERVICE_NAME|SID)\s*=\s*([^)\r\n]+)'
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DHM8x9/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3ASERVICE_NAME%7CSID)%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*(%5B%5E%5Cr%5Cn)%5D%2B)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:SERVICE_NAME|SID)` - a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) that matches either `SERVICE_NAME` or `SID`
- `\s*=\s*` -  a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `([^)\r\n]+)` - Group 1: any chars, one or more occurrences, other than `)`, CR and LF (excluded because of `.` in the original attempt).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single capturing group to prevent getting 2 groups where one will be empty due to the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), you could move the alternation to the start of the pattern between SERVICE_NAME and SID `(?:SERVICE_NAME|SID)` and make it a non capturing group.

If both words can not be part of a larger word, you could prepend a wordboundary `\b` to the pattern.

```
(?:SERVICE_NAME|SID)\s?=\s?(.+?)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:SERVICE_NAME|SID)` Match either SERVICE_NAME or SID
- `\s?=\s?` Match a `=` surrounded by an optional whitespace char
- `(.+?)\)` Match any character except a newline non greedy, then match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO3g6l/1)